# AMP swift font not loading from CDN

Tags: wordpress, fonts, cdn, amp-html, truetype

I have a strange issue going on in my Wordpress website.

I'm using the AMP and AMP cache plugins to handle this format when accessing from a mobile phone to the posts on my website.

For example, when reaching this url from a Google search:

https://www.sectorasegurador.es/los-mejores-seguros-de-salud/amp/

The `icomoon.ttf` does get loaded (**status 200**), however, they are not visible (**pay attention to the top right corner**)

[image]

Now, If I refresh this page, the icons are visible.

On both situations, I can see that the resourse is loaded. You can see here the request when coming from Google results:

[image]

And here, when refreshing the page:

[image]

How come that when this resource comes from AMP's cdn, my icons are not visible?

Comment: Here is the url where you can test what happens. https://www-sectorasegurador-es.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.sectorasegurador.es/los-mejores-seguros-de-salud/amp/

Comment: I am going to clear amp cache but I need a private and public key. I will do that later. Anyway, does anybody have an idea about why this url is not showing the font icons? thanks

Comment: I went through the Google update-cache guide, got an OK for the request to purge the mentioned url and nothing happens.